# How to exclude user logged and other users that belong to the same object

Tags: django, django-views

I'm making a ScrumBoard project, I wanna add to my board users that is not the user logged or users that are already part of that board. I use a UserBoard table to store id of users and id of boards that it belongs to. A board can have more than one user.
Problem is: In views.py I'm trying to show (In a droplist) these users with exclude, but I didn't succeed, users showed to me are the user logged that have other board and user that already belong to the board that I'm in.
Sorry for my English and messy code.

```
def add_user_to_board(request, board_id):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user = BoardMemberForm(request.POST)
    if user.is_valid():
        board = Board.objects.get(pk=board_id)
        utente = user.cleaned_data['user']
        utente1 = utente.get_user()
        new_user = BoardMember(board=board, user=utente1)
        new_user.save()
        boardmember = BoardMember.objects.filter(board=board)
        #return HttpResponseRedirect("dashboard/")
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard/board/?board_id=%s' % (board_id, request.path))
        #user.fields['user'].queryset = BoardMember.objects.none()
        return render(request, "dashboard.html", {'board': boardmember})
  else:
      user = BoardMemberForm()
      board = Board.objects.get(pk=board_id)
      #usern = request.session.get('username')
      #userexclude = User.objects.get(username=usern)
      appoggio_b = BoardMember.objects.select_related('board').filter(board=board)
      appoggio_u = BoardMember.objects.select_related('user').filter(board=board)
      list_board = [item.board for item in appoggio_b]
      list_user = [item.user for item in appoggio_u]
      #board_a = appoggio_b.get_board()
      #user_a = appoggio_u.get_user()
      user.fields['user'] = BoardMember.objects.all()#.exclude(Q(board=list_board)).exclude(~Q(user=list_user))
      #BoardMember.objects.exclude(id__in=BoardMember.objects.get(id=kwargs['board_id']).user_ids.all())
return render(request, "add_user_to_board.html", {'form': user,  'board': board})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_board` and `list_user` are lists of instances hence you should use `__in` lookup in excludes.

```
user.fields['user'] = BoardMember.objects.exclude(Q(board__id=list_board)).exclude(~Q(user__in=list_user))
```

If that won't work try to pass IDs instead of objects.

```
list_board = [item.board.id for item in appoggio_b]
list_user = [item.user.id for item in appoggio_u]
```

Comment: We learn all the time, don't be too hard on yourself. Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.